# Http not redirecting to https nginx

Tags: nginx, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have set up  letsEncrypt free ssl with certbot on ubuntu 14.04 from digitalocean tutorial. 
If anyone tries to access the page on 80 ( http://gw2axiom.com ) , it shows 404 not found. 
If you try https://gw2axiom.com it will work normally. After that, http will redirect to 443.
**What could be the reason?** 
My **nginx** config file is the following :

```
   # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/gw2axiom.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gw2axiom.com www.gw2axiom.com;
    root /home/forge/gw2axiom.com/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gw2axiom.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gw2axiom.com/privkey.pem;
    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;
    location /forum/ { try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/index.php?$query_string; }
    location /forum/api { try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/api.php?$query_string; }
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        } 
    location /forum/admin { try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/admin.php?$query_string; }
    location /flarum {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }


        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;


    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/gw2axiom.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/gw2axiom.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* \.html$ {
        expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 1M;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml
               application/javascript
               application/json
               application/vnd.ms-fontobject
               application/x-font-ttf
               application/x-web-app-manifest+json
               application/xhtml+xml
               application/xml
               font/opentype
               image/svg+xml
               image/x-icon
               text/css
               text/plain
               text/xml;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";


    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.gw2axiom.com gw2axiom.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/gw2axiom.com/after/*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before your current `server` entry:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name gw2axiom.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

After that restart your nginx webserver and everything should work fine.